# How to use dynamic values with type-checked i18next?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I created a custom type for i18next in order to type-check my translations:

```
import { resources } from '@locales/i18n';

import 'i18next';

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: (typeof resources)['en'];
  }
}
```

This works perfectly fine for `t('common.error')`, but how do I solve the issue when I have a variable?

`t(link.title)` - this will cause `TS error Argument of type '[SomeType]' is not assignable to parameter of type`

I can put `t(link.title as any)` but I hate using any. I am using latest version of i18next and react-i18next. How can I tell typescript that variable is of the same type I defined in `CustomTypeOptions`?